# AttributeError: module 'django.contrib' has no attribute 'admin'

Tags: python, django

When I run  **python manage.py runserver**,encounter the  following errors

```
    Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 
0x10fb4cc80>
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/apple/Desktop/learning_log/ll_env/lib/python3.7/site- 
  packages/django/apps/config.py", line 118, in create
    cls = getattr(mod, cls_name)
AttributeError: module 'django.contrib' has no attribute 'admin'
```

and below

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'AutocompleteSelect' from 'django.contrib.admin.widgets' (/Users/apple/Desktop/learning_log/ll_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/widgets.py)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you have created your django project using `django>=2.0`, where you are trying to run it using `django<2.0`.

I am assuming that from this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'AutocompleteSelect' from 'django.contrib.admin.widgets' (/Users/apple/Desktop/learning_log/ll_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/widgets.py)
```

Because `AutocompleteSelect` did not exist in `django/contrib/admin/widgets` before version **2.0**. Reference can be found [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.0a1/django/contrib/admin/widgets.py).

So, please make sure that you are using the same django version which you have used to create the project and using it to run the project.

Comment: Thanks for your anwser.I used python3.7 and django1.11 before. And it seems I need to upgrade django>2.0.I have run "pip3 install --upgrade django".But the error still there.I need to do more?